# dd-wrt EoIP not working at all - need to bridge two routers across the web

Tags: router, dd-wrt

I am having problems getting an EoIP working in dd-wrt. Basically, I want to bridge my home and office networks. Both locations have static IPs. Can't really figure out what's going on here or if it is a bug with the software (since there are a few I've ran across that I've tried to fix).

Here is my setup. Both routers are running the std package.

Router 1: Release: 08/07/10 (SVN revision: 14896) 
Router 2: Release: 11/21/10 (SVN revision: 15778)

I have set up per this wiki page: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/EoIP_Routing However I am having problems even being able to ping each other's internal EoIP address, let alone any static routes for traffic between clients behind the routers.

xx.xx is to preserve my networks security

Here is the output of both nvram grepping oet1_:

```
Router 1: 

oet1_rem=24.249.xx.xx (this is router 2's WAN IP) 
oet1_bridged=0 
oet1_multicast=0 
oet1_mtu=1500 
oet1_netmask=255.255.255.0 
oet1_en=1 
rc_startup=nvram set oet1_ip=$(nvram get wan_ipaddr) 
oet1_pt=0 
oet1_nat=1 
size: 25609 bytes (7159 left) 
oet1_id=1 
oet1_mssfix=0 
oet1_ip=68.102.xx.xx (this is router 1's WAN IP) 
oet1_ipaddr=192.168.202.1 
oet1_shaper=0 
oet1_comp=0 
oet1_fragment=0 

Router 2: 

oet1_rem=68.102.xx.xx (this is router 1's WAN IP) 
oet1_bridged=0 
oet1_netmask=255.255.255.0 
size: 19571 bytes (45965 left) 
oet1_en=1 
rc_startup=nvram set oet1_ip=$(nvram get wan_ipaddr) 
oet1_pt=0 
oet1_id=1 
oet1_mssfix=0 
oet1_ip=24.249.xx.xx (this is router 2's WAN IP) 
oet1_ipaddr=192.168.202.2 
oet1_shaper=0 
oet1_comp=0 
oet1_fragment=0
```

Btw, I had to manually enter the "nvram set oet1_ip=$(nvram get wan_ipaddr)" line into the startup script because I was getting 1.2.3.4 as my oet1_ip address.

I log in to each router and try to ping the other 192.168.202.1 or 192.168.202.2 addresses. The local IP works, but the remote IP address fails. This might be a newb mistake, but is there any authentication that needs to be done for this to work? I am struggling to get this set up. I have also set up static routes, but I feel at this point it is not relevant to show them because I can't even ping the remote gateway, let alone try to do any routing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot find much documentation on EoIP so not sure how it should be configured but until you figure it out you should setup something like [Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi2/) if you just use Windows or [Wippien](http://www.wippien.com/) if you use Windows/Linux so you can get your computers talking as if they were on the same LAN segment.

I haven't used it in a while but Hamachi is really cool you have like a friends list of all the people in the "LAN" that you have an encrypted chat between them.

Comment: Yeah I really like Hamachi, but I'm looking to bridge the entire networks, not just each PC.  I have some embedded IP devices (cameras, etc) that wouldn't really work with a client based approach.

Comment: You might be able to get it to do that... have not set it up this way because I never had to but there is a how-to on the wiki check it out looks like what you want. http://logmeinwiki.com/wiki/Hamachi:Routed_Tunneling_/_Bridging_Networks_Together

Answer (score 0):

Since you're running build 14986 have you looked at this issue/fix since "EoIP is working fine, but a bug in the Web GUI prevents reassigning a bridged oet interface to anything other than br0"?

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/FON_Hotspot_on_La_Fonera#EoIP

Also, why are you running NAT on only one endpoint when they both appear to be hiding internal networks?

Is there any reason you can't run an updated build on that device?

Comment: That's the newest build for the hardware I have.  WRT54G v1.1.

I did not set the nat variable on the routers, the software did that for me.  Why do you say they both appear to be hiding internal networks?